# How to position a div sticky to the end of a mobile page?

Tags: html, css

Desired result: having, on both Chrome Android and Safari iOS, **a div which sticks at the bottom of the page, without overlapping with content which may take more than 100% of the visible viewport**

In other words, I want **the `.bottom-element` to always be at the very bottom of the page (vertically)**, no matter if the elements above it takes <, = or > than 100% of the viewport / screen height.

```
<style>
.container {
   height: 100vh: // Note: it's okay if this variable
   width: 100vw;
}

.bottom-element {
   position: sticky;
   bottom: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <!-- other statically positioned children of variable height here -->
  <div class="bottom-element">
</div>
```

Actual result: The below achieves the result, as long as the children don't take more than the window height.

[image]

However, when the document becomes longer **the `.bottom-element` will overlap with other elements**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean `sticky` at the end of a page? The purpose of a `sticky` element is to "catch" on the page when it is scrolled past, but if an element is at the end of the page, it literally cannot be scrolled past, making the use of `sticky` redundant

Comment: @Laif I mean I want the element to always be at the very edge of the page (vertically), no matter if the content above it takes less, equal or more than 100% of the viewport height

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: also added some explanatory wireframes

Comment: This wireframe seems to assume a static height to the entire webpage that is unchanging depending on content, which is very different from the way things usually work, is this your intention?

Comment: @Laif The height can be variable. if you have a solution that use a variable height for allowing any amount of content, go ahead

Comment: Try using position fixed instead of sticky

Comment: @AndrewRivera I did

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
.container {
   height: calc(100vh - yourBottomElementHeight);
   width: 100vw;
}

.bottom-element {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Example

if your bottom element height approx 100px than you will use like this

```
.container {
   height: calc(100vh - 100px);
   width: 100vw;
}
```

After use above code your bottom element not overlapped. You either use position sticky or absolute. Here I mention position absolute because position sticky does not not work on safari browser.

Comment: Hi @denishkumar.  I'm getting the overlapping effect when elements above bottom element take the whole screen

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
   height: calc(100vh - 100px);
   width: 100vw;
   overflow-y: auto;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}

.bottom-element {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: red;
   height:100px;
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try with this one.
Update your HTML structure with below HTML/CSS code.

<style>
.container {
  display:flex;
  height:100%;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.longer-element{
   flex:1;
   overflow-y:auto;
   overflow-x:hidden;
}

</style>


<div class="container">  
  <div class="longer-element">longer text</div>
  <div class="bottom-element">bottom sticky element</div>
</div>

Now without used of position absolute , sticky or fixed, your element always visible on bottom.
```